# EventBridge API Destination with POST returns 405 status code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-event-bridge, localstack

I am trying to create EventBridge API Destination with POST as http method using localstack. I am trying to connect to my service which is running in local docker container. I Get following error:

> "Error parsing parameter '--invocation-endpoint': Unable to retrieve
> http://host.docker.internal:port_no/api/my-endpoint received non 200
> status code of 405"

If I use wget for the same endpoint it works fine. Issue occurs only during create-api-destination.

Following is my command:

```
awslocal events create-api-destination
--name "api-name"
--connection-arn "connection-arn"
--invocation-rate-limit-per-second 10
--http-method POST
--invocation-endpoint "http://host.docker.internal:port_no/api/my-endpoint"
```

Also tried the following:

```
aws --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 events create-api-destination
--name "api-name"
--connection-arn "connection-arn"
--invocation-rate-limit-per-second 10
--http-method POST
--invocation-endpoint "http://host.docker.internal:port_no/api/my-endpoint"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried doing this in a real AWS account, with a real endpoint URL that is accessible on the Internet? Or have you just tried on LocalStack?

Comment: I have tried other endpoint which is running in Azure app service. it fails there too with the same error.

Comment: I enabled --debug option and found that, aws is making GET call instead of POST call. Its ignoring --http-method key. _Log Details_: 2023-04-13 17:17:15,871 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTP connection (1): host.docker.internal:port_no
2023-04-13 17:17:15,938 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - http://host.docker.internal:port_no"GET /api/my-endpoint HTTP/1.1" 405 0
2023-04-13 17:17:15,939 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue just by single quote for the endpoint.

```
    aws --endpoint-url localhost:4566 events create-api-destination 
    --name "api-name" 
    --connection-arn "connection-arn" 
    --invocation-rate-limit-per-second 10 
    --http-method POST 
    --invocation-endpoint "'host.docker.internal:port_no/api/my-endpoint'"
```